# Flash AS2 clickTag giving errors

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, clicktag

I am having some real problems with Flash banners I'm creating and adding clickTags to a timeline.

I had been using this bit of code, on the instance of a button I'd created, and it worked...

```
on(release){
    getURL(_root.clickTAG, "_blank");
}
```

But the media agency tells me it's better to place the code on the timeline directly (which contains the instance of the button) with some slightly different code...

```
EBStd.Init();

buttonInstance.onRelease = function() {
  EBStd.Clickthrough();
}
```

So I've tried this method, but when I 'Export as Movie...' I get the following errors...

```
Scene=Scene 1, layer=ClickTag, frame=1, Line 4  Operator '=' must be followed by an operand
Scene=Scene 1, layer=ClickTag, frame=1, Line 5  Unexpected '}' encountered
```

So, put simply, I cannot get this newer code to work! Agh.

I have made sure that "buttonInstance" is the name of the actual button on the "ClickTag" layer (on the timeline), but it doesn't help.

Can anyone please help me understand where I am going wrong?

[image]

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: What version of Flash are you using?

Comment: I'm using Flash CS6 (if that's the answer you're looking for?).

Comment: Unfortunately the version of Flash I have doesn't allow me to execute ActionScript2 code so I can't help you debug; however, looking at your code, everything looks good. I suspect that there may be something else that is the issue, but is being masked as the issue you are being presented with.  Do you have _any_ other actionscript in your project?

Comment: Nope. There's no other AS in there as far as I can see. Very odd.

Comment: That is very odd.  Does the problem occur in _all_ flash projects or just this one? Have you checked that the project settings are set to build for ActionScript 2? I think that setting is in the Publish Settings area.

Comment: Yep, it's set for AS2 in the Publish Settings. I must have done something wrong somewhere...?

Comment: @Chuck - And what is your flash player's version?

Comment: @helloflash Not sure. But I don't think the Flash Player comes into it, as I can't even export the movie file.

Comment: @Chuck - If your Flash player version is under 6 (player 5), your new code can't work. That's the reason why i ask you this question.

Comment: I'm using Flash CS6. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Chuck - No. File > Publish Settings... > Player. If your player's version is 5, give it the value 6.

Comment: @Chuck - Do you find your Player version?